# Using Turkish Chars on HTML page

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, turkish

I think charset:windows-1254 should make the Turkish chars available on page but they dont come, here is my full code:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
<title>Marmara İnşaat</title>
</head>

<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginheight="0"     marginwidth="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="img/topbkg.gif">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><img border="0" src="img/toplogo.gif" width="142" height="66"></td>
    <td width="50%">
      <p align="right"><img border="0" src="img/topright.gif" width="327" height="66">    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"     background="img/blackline.gif">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%"><font color="#B8C0F0" face="Arial" size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      Ana Sayfa&nbsp;&nbsp; </b></font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p style="margin-left: 20"><b><font color="#B8C0F0" face="Arial" size="20">&nbsp;    </font></b><font face="Arial" size="20" color="#0000FF"><p><b>Tüm müşterilerimizin Ramazan bayramı kutlu olsun!</b></p>
<p><b>Mutlu Bayramlar.</b></p>
</font></p>
<p style="margin-left: 20"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font></p>
<p style="margin-left: 20"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font></p>
<p style="margin-left: 20"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font></p>
<p style="margin-left: 20"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000000">&nbsp;</font>    </p>
<p style="margin-left: 20" align="center"><font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="1">©
Tüm Haklari Saklidir www.marmarains.com</font></p>
<p style="margin-right: 20" align="right"><font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="1">
<br>Marmara İnşaat,Dekorasyon,Gida<br></font></p>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"          background="img/botline.gif">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%"><img border="0" src="img/botline.gif" width="41" height="12"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

For example instead of "Marmara Insaat" I would like to have "Marmara İnşaat"

Thanks!

Comment: What is the file ***actually*** encoded in?

Comment: @deceze I didnt get quite the question? But file extension is htm, index.htm

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">` just tells the browser what the document is *supposedly* encoded in. What is it *actually* encoded in? What encoding is it saved as in your text editor? If you can't answer that, read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: @deceze Changed then encoding with Notepad++ to UTF-8 now working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The document has not been saved in the windows-1254 encoding. Many programs cannot even produce data in that encoding. But when properly written in that encoding, the page works as is (well, in this respect; there are coding errors in other areas there.

It is however generally (and officially) advisable to use UTF-8 instead, as you have now done, according a comment. This, too, requires a match between the actual encoding (in which the data is saved) and the declared encoding (as per a `meta` tag or otherwise).